# Objective C: Get bounds of UIView in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, position, bounds

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that I created in the InterfaceBuilder. I added an UIView to the UITableViewCell and also added an Outlet for it. Now I need to know it´s position in the specific UITableViewCell.

I wrote the following code in my custom UITableViewCell

WorkentryCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WorkentryCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@end
```

WorkentryCell.m

```
#import "WorkentryCell.h"

@implementation WorkentryCell

@synthesize view1;

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if(self) {
      NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view1.bounds.size.height, self.view1.bounds.size.width);
      NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view1.bounds.origin.x, self.view1.bounds.origin.y);
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)setNeedsDisplay
{
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view1.bounds.size.height, self.projectLabel.bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view1.bounds.origin.x, self.projectLabel.bounds.origin.y);
}
```

but everything I get is:

2012-11-14 15:01:43.943 TestApp[883:907] 0.000000, 0.000000

2012-11-14 15:01:43.944 TestApp[883:907] 0.000000, 0.000000

Can you please tell me why there is no information about position and size of the UIView?

Thanks
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have valid size in the init method. You should put this code in the setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: I added the code to the -(void)setNeedsDisplay of my custom UITableViewCell but I get the same result

Comment: Is view1 added to you custom view? Could you please attach the code of your custom view to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave. I added the rest of the code, but it´s not much, because I only made a small example before adding this to my project. view1 is a normal UIView. The Outlet is connected properly.

Comment: Please add NSLOG(@"%@",self.view1); to your logs to make sure that the view is there.

Comment: You´re right. It´s (null). But why? It is a normal UIView and I checked the Outlet.